# Python | Lambda | Decrypt EFS data and send to S3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, gnupg, amazon-efs

Hi I am looking for a start of Python Lambda function which will decrypt data from EFS and send it to S3 bucket.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/efs.html

I looked this link but i don't think any methods mentioned are helpful. Please suggest where I can start writing this.

My code currently assumes that, it receives encrypted file which will then decrypt it using gnupg and send the file back to S3.

But this doesn't fulfil my complete requirement - when a new file lands to the EFS. This can use Cloudwatch events when the final trigger file is copied.The Lambda function picks up the encrypted file, decrypts them, adds the required metadata and sends them to the S3 bucket.

```
import boto3
import gnupg

# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    Key = "/efs/iamfile.txt"
    stream = open(Key, "rb")
    decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt_file(stream)
    bucketName = "op-efs-uki-vpc"
    outPutname = "decrypted_data"
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_file(Key,bucketName,outPutname)
```

Comment: Why do you need lambda function?

Comment: @betontalpfa-- A File decryption lambda function is executed when a new file lands to the EFS. This can use Cloudwatch events when the final trigger file is copied.The function picks up the encrypted file, decrypts them, adds the required metadata and sends them to the S3 bucket.

Comment: @betontalpfa- What options do we have more?

Comment: @HBruijn - Could you please suggest me here

Comment: What is the required metadata? Have you looked at: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry You can ignore this for now

Comment: @Kally what? ignore what?

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry- I mean to say, for time being we can ignore the metadata

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry- i am just focusing on , file to get picked up from EFS, decrypt it using key and send it S3